# 13 error (type doesn't match) when comparing two dates within a conditional instruction (vba)

Tags: vba, date, if-statement

I've wrote the following code to delete rows of worskheet 2 in which value of column 7 (a date) is less tan a value of a certain cell of worksheet 1:

```
Sub delete()

Dim listaops As Worksheet
Dim RToDelete As Range
Dim DTtoCompare As Date
Dim DTofOp As Date
Dim i As Integer

Set listaops = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QryOperacionesComprasyAmort0239")
Set RToDelete = Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown))

DTtoCompare = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value

For i = RToDelete.Cells.Count + 1 To 2 Step -1

    DTofOp = listaops.Cells(i, 7).Value

    If DTofOp < DTtoCompare Then
        Cells(i, 7).EntireRow.delete
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

When it arrives to the instruction in which I set DTtoCompare: `DTtoCompare = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value` I get the following:

> 13 Error: Types mismatch

I guess it is because variables are not right formatted or right assigned to a date format, I have tried so many things without success.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Try wrapping `CDate()` around `ThisWorkbook.....Value`

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs tried but still the same error. I tried also to define DTofOp and DTtoCompare as ranges and apply .value when comparing both within conditional statement, but in this case it doesn't read it well and delete all rows.

Comment: Add `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value` above that line and see what you get in the immediate window (Ctrl + G).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen if the value isn't a date (eg. February 29th isn't coming this year). You can test this with IsDate before setting the typed variable.

Another way would be using DateDiff, but you'd likely end up with the same problem there.

**Update**
A simple example of CDate:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim s As String
    Dim d As Date

    s = "12/12/2017"
    d = CDate(s)
End Sub
```

Comment: In my case, the date to compare is 12/12/2017, would you know how can I coerce it to be a date? It becomes clear that the problema is not te value, but the format